# Adding some html to body tag with append but Tesseract function not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have added some html to body tag with append. But When I put  `runOCR(url)` Tesseract OCR not working.How to come up from this problem.

Here Is My Code:

```
    function test(){
var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = 
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js
     /1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);


    var large = '<div id="text" class="form-group"> \
     <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Image URL" />\
     <input type="button" id="go_button" value="Run" />\
     <div id="ocr_status"> </div>\
     <div>\
        <label>Filed1:</label>\
           <textarea id="text1" ></textarea>\
     </div>\
     </div>';
     $('body').append(large);

     $(".form-group").css({
      position: "fixed",
      top: "20px",
      right: "180px",
 'border-radius': '25px',
     'border': '2px solid #73AD21',
 'padding': '20px', 
 'background': '#FFF8DC',
      "font-size": "1.5em",
  "z-index": "1000",

    });
      function runOCR(url) {
     Tesseract.recognize(url)
    .then(function(result) {
       console.log(result);
        document.getElementById("text1").value = result.text;
      }).progress(function(result) {
      document.getElementById("ocr_status").innerText = 
      result["status"] + " (" +
        (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
         });      
          }
    document.getElementById("url")
  .addEventListener("input", function(e) {
   var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    runOCR(url);

     });
```

Comment: If this is a browser_action popup, it has its own devtools: right-click the popup and click ”inspect”. You'll probably see an error about the script being disallowed by CSP. To fix it, either put the tesseract.js into your extension and load it from there as a local script, or specify a custom CSP in manifest.json.

Comment: i also put tesseract.js into local and load it,but still not working.

Comment: Use devtools to debug the code.

Comment: ok,sir, I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrote a minimal example to run tesseract.js in a chrome extension, you can check and hope it helps:

https://github.com/jeromewu/tesseract.js-chrome-extension

main code snippet below:

```
const doOCR = () => {
  const image = document.getElementById('image');
  const result = document.getElementById('result');

  const { TesseractWorker } = Tesseract;
  const worker = new TesseractWorker({
    workerPath: chrome.runtime.getURL('js/worker.min.js'),
    langPath: chrome.runtime.getURL('traineddata'),
    corePath: chrome.runtime.getURL('js/tesseract-core.wasm.js'),
  });

  worker.recognize(image)
    .then(({ text }) => {
      result.innerHTML = `<p>OCR Result:</p><p>${text}</p>`;
    })
}

const startBtn = document.getElementById('start-btn');
startBtn.onclick = doOCR;
```